# Is there a way to dynamically build a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am totally new to python and basically new to programming in general.
I have a college assignment that involves scanning through a CSV file and storing each row as a list. My file is a list of football data for the premier league season so the CSV file is structured as follows:

```
date; home; away; homegoals; awaygoals; result;
01/01/2012; Man United; Chelsea; 1; 2; A;
01/02/2012; Man City; Arsenal; 1; 1; D;
```

etc etc.

At the moment each column is stored in a variable:

```
date = row[0]
home = row[1]
away = row[2]
homegoals = row[4]
awaygoals = row[5]
```

So I can currently access for example, all games with more than three goals

```
totalgoals = homegoals+awaygoals

if totalgoals > 3:
   print(date, home, homegoals, awaygoals, away)
```

I can access all games which featured a certain team:

```
if (home or away) == "Man United":
   print(date, home, homegoals, awaygoals, away)
```

Very basic, I know. 
I am looking to be able to track things more in depth. So for example I would like to be able to access results where the team has not won in 3 games etc.
I would like to be able to find out if a team is on a low scoring run.

Now, from reading online for a while it seems to me the way you do this is with a combination of a dictionary and list(s).

So far:

```
import csv

with open('premier_league_data_1819.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

dates = []
hometeams = []
awayteams =[]
homegoals = []
awaygoals = []
results = []

next(readCSV)

for row in readCSV:
    date = row[0]
    home = row[1]
    away = row[2]
    hg = int(row[3]) #Home Goals
    ag = int(row[4]) #Away Goals
    ftr = row[6]     #Result


    dates.append(date)
    hometeams.append(home)
    awayteams.append(away)
    homegoals.append(hg)
    awaygoals.append(ag)
    results.append(ftr)
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction on this I would be grateful. 
It would be good to know the best way of achieving this so I am not spinning my wheels getting more confused.

I think to start I would need to first store all of a teams games in a list & then add that list to a dictionary that holds all teams records with the team name as a key.

Comment: Note that `if (home or away) == "Man United":` doesn't do what you expect. For what you expect you need `if "Man United" in (home, away):`

Comment: Of course, I see now. flawed statement but as it returned results I missed the error.

Answer (score 1):

Good that you're already using the `csv` module - it'll save you a lot of headache with parsing your data.  You may also check out the `DictReader` class in that module - it would return rows with column names as keys for you without some of the extra processing I'm including below. You want to group the stats for each game together so you can do aggregation.  I'd approach that with something like this:

```
games = []

for row in readCSV:
  date, home, away, hg, ag, ftr = row[0:-1]  # this is called 'unpacking'
  # alternatively: date, home, away, hg, ag, ftr, _ = row
  # using _ this way to consume and ignore a value is another python idiom

  # This creates a dictionary where you can retrieve values by key, rather than index
  games.append(dict(date=date, home=home, away=away, hg=hg, ag=ag, ftr=ftr)
```

Now that you have a list of dictionaries, one representing each game, you can interact with them a bit more naturally:

```
games[0]['home']  # The home team of the first game
# All 'Man United' games
man_united = [game for game in games if 'Man United' in (game['home'], game['away'])]  
sum(game['hg'] for game in games)  # total number of home goals for all games.
```

Comment: date, home, away, hg, ag, ftr = row
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 6)

Comment: It's because there is a final empty string in the row: `['date', 'home', 'away', 'homegoals', 'awaygoals', 'result', '']`. Use a slice: `date, home, away, hg, ag, ftr = row[0:-1]`

Comment: Updated for the comments - the blank string at the end of row counted as a value.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the method [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) that you could use in this way:

```
data = []
with open('premier-league.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
     for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

print(data[0][' home']) # <-- note the space
#=>  Man United
```

Note that in your csv after the delimiter there is a space, should be better if you can change the csv file to:

```
date;home;away;homegoals;awaygoals;result;
01/01/2012;ManUnited;Chelsea;1;2;A;
01/02/2012;ManCity;Arsenal;1;1;D;
```

Alternatively, use

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)
```